# Jquery datatables - selected row hightlight is not working in second page

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

I have pagination in my datable and i implemented selected row highlight feature...This feature(row highlight) is working in first page but second and third pages are not working.

I have updated the code in jsfiddle , please take look into advise .

```
var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
    "aaData": [
        ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        ["five", "six", "seven","eight"],
        ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

    ],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "two_button",
       "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "aaSorting": [
        [4, "desc"]
    ],
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "aoColumns": [{
        "sWidth": "70%",
            "sClass": "center",
            "bSortable": false
    }, {
        "sWidth": "70%",
            "sClass": "center",
            "bSortable": false
    }, {
        "sWidth": "70%",
            "sClass": "center",
            "bSortable": false
    }, {
        "sWidth": "70%",
            "sClass": "center",
            "bSortable": false
    }, ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[0];
        },
            "sClass": "prodNbr first",
            "aTargets": [0]
    }, {
        "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[1];
        },
            "sClass": "Description",
            "aTargets": [1]
    }, {
        "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[2];
        },
            "sClass": "Partid",
            "aTargets": [2]
    }, {
        "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[3];
        },
            "sClass": "Description",
            "aTargets": [3]
    }]

});


$('#products tbody tr').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) $(this).removeClass('selected');
    else
    {
        $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/16/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Why your approach did not work

The reason your `click` event isn't happening because the `tr`s are dynamically created. The `click` events are only attached to elements that exist *and aren't attached to elements which will be added later*.

#### Solution

So I suggest you use `live` or `delegate` to bind the `click` events to the `tr`s.

```
$('body').delegate('#products tbody tr', "click", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) $(this).removeClass('selected');
    else {
        $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

The reason we're binding it to `<body>` is because it'll be existant all the time and your events would be delegated to the `tr`s from there.

#### Extras

If you're using a later version of jQuery,(**which you must**) it'd be advisable to use `on`,

```
$('body').on("click", '#products tbody tr' ,function () {
//your code
});
```

#### More info on the methods used

**`delegate`**

- Docs : http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- What it does : Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

**`on`**

- Docs : http://api.jquery.com/on/
- What it does : Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

#### Demos

- for jQuery 1.6 : http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/18/
- for jQuery 1.9 : http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/19/

#### Edits

One more way would be to use `live()` (since you're using jQuery 1.6). This would ensure that the `click` is bound to all elements. (even dynamic)

```
$('#products tbody tr').live("click", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) $(this).removeClass('selected');
    else {
        $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Very good Explanation. Thanks. I'm using 1.6 and i have implemented .delegate. Its working without pagination, but if get more data with pagination , its not working in my application.

Comment: check my updated answer and see if it works for you @user2444474

Comment: and could u make a demo for ur new problem?

Comment: I try to simulate in jsfiddle ,here working working good. but its not working for me.Any way just look into the way design..http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/21/

Comment: @user2444474 i dont get u :) pls explain more :)